# refreshing the data retrieved from database

Tags: java, database, swing, reload

I have a JFrame with a JTabbedPane.

In one of those panes, say `compose`, I save some new data in table. The other pane, say `drafts`, displays the saved data in the same table.

When you first login, the data saved in previous run of application is displayed in the `drafts` but if during the same run I save some new data from `compose` and then switch to `draft` pane, the data retrieved from the database doesnt have the new saved data.

In other words how can I refresh the data retrieved?

Comment: please improve this issue's tags

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to ask questions. Show us an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) of [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)... Capital letters are fun too.

Comment: how's the data being saved? and how is it displayed?

Comment: data is being saved using sql  queries. I want updated table contents be displayed when i switch to my drafts pane.

Answer (score 0):

When you update a JComponent, it needs to be told to reload. So whenever you make the call to update your `draft` pane's data, you should also call `draft.revalidate()`.